# How to set textbox value using actionform in Struts

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, struts, actionform

Good day,

The following is my jsp code, I use this to create a datepicker text box :

```
<head>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="scripts/jquery-ui.css" />
     <script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 

     $(function(){ 
        //$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/icon_calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true
            });
        });
    </script>   
</head>

//some code here
<td class="value"><html:text property="campaignurl" size="50" maxlength="1000" /></td>

<td width="40%">
    <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="periodFrom" />
</td>
```

The following is my action.java code (code behind) :

```
System.out.println(thisForm.getPeriodFrom()); //this is working fine
thisForm.setCampaignurl("this is url"); // this is working fine, brower display "this is url" in textbox campaignurl
thisForm.setPeriodFrom("09/05/2013"); // this display blank in browser.
```

Because I want to user JavaScript/Jquery to create the datepicker, thus I change the textbox into `<input/>` instead of `<html:text />`.

However, I can set value for `<html:text />` which is the `campaignurl` easily, but I cant set value for the `<input/>` textbox which is `periodForm` .

Suppose this is simple to done, however I cant find solution after I spending long time on it.

Kindly advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`struts-bean.tld`](http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/struts-taglib/tagreference.html#struts-bean.tld):

```
<input type="text" 
       id="datepicker" 
       name="periodFrom" 
       value="<bean:write name="yourForm" property="periodFrom"/>" />
```

See more in [*Package `org.apache.struts.taglib.bean`*](http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/struts-taglib/apidocs/org/apache/struts/taglib/bean/package-summary.html)

---

With [JSTL](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-135995.html):

```
<input type="text" 
       id="datepicker" 
       name="periodFrom" 
       value="<c:out value="${yourForm.periodFrom}"/>" />
```

See more in [*JSTL Core `<c:out>` Tag*](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jstl_core_out_tag.htm)